# Storing the return value of a recursive function in a variable in ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, recursion

I'm working on a problem to find the first pair of numbers in an array that sums to a specific target. I have to return the pair which its rightmost index appears first. So say target is `10` and pairs found are `[5,5]` at indices `1,5` and `[3,7]` at indices `3,4` I'd have to return `[3,7]`. I have the recursive part working, problem is it returns a hash with the leftmost index as key and the pair as value. I'm trying to call this recursive function from another function (#sum_pairs) so that I can then format the output I need, but when I do that and try to store it in  the variable pairs all it returns is an empty hash, even though it returns the completed hash when I just call it from the console.

Heres my code:

```
    $starts = [0]

    def sum_pairs(ints, s)
     pairs = find_pairs(ints,s)
     pairs[pairs.keys.min]
    end

    def find_pairs(ints, s)
     sums = {}

     ints.each_with_index do |n, idx|
       next if idx < $starts.last
       right_idx = completes(ints, idx, n, s)

       if right_idx.nil?
        return sums if idx == (ints.length - 1)
        next
      else
       sums[right_idx] = [n, (s - n)]
       $starts << idx
       sums.merge!(sum_pairs(ints[0...right_idx], s))
       sums
      end
     end
    end

    def completes(ints, idx, n, s )
     ints.each_with_index do |num, index|
      next if index <= idx
      return index if num == s - n
     end
     nil
   end
```

I know I could do this with iteration an it would probably be more or equally efficient, but I'm trying to use this to better understand recursion, thank you!

Comment: can you provide a few more examples of the desired result? You say you should return the pair where the leftmost element appears first. Do you mean appear first in term of index? If so, shouldn't you return `[5,5]` because index 1 appears before index 3?

Comment: Can you show the code for the `completes` method?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say rightmost. Just changed that and added the completes method

Comment: A sample input that produces the problem would also be useful - help people reproduce the problem, rather than requiring them to guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mean no offense but it took me a while to understand your code. You may need to name your methods and parameters more explicitly when you intend other people to read.

As an outsider, It took me a while to understand the `s` throughout your code actually represented the `target_number`. It's also a good idea to comment your methods indicating how to use them and what the expected return value should be.

```
integers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,3,4,5,6,7,8,4,3,2,1]
target_number = 10
$current_index = [0]

def set_right_index(integers, leftmost_index, leftmost_int, target_number)
  integers.each_with_index do |int, i|
    next if i <= leftmost_index
    return i if int == target_number - leftmost_int
  end
  nil
end

def find_pairs(integers, target_number)
  sums = {}

  integers.each_with_index do |int, i|
    next if i < $current_index.max
    # debug = []
    # debug << set_right_index(integers, i, int, target_number)
    right_index = set_right_index(integers, i, int, target_number)

    if right_index.nil?
      return sums if i == integers.length - 1
      next
    end

    sums[right_index] = [int, (target_number - int)]
    $current_index << i
    # sums.merge! sum_pairs(integers[0..right_index], target_number)  #<= calling this returns a `stack overflow error` :P because the methods just keeps calling itself
    sums
  end
end
```

Now, if you call

```
find_pairs(integers, target_number)
```

the return value will look like this:

```
{8=>[1, 9],
 7=>[2, 8],
 6=>[3, 7],
 5=>[4, 6],
 11=>[5, 5],
 10=>[6, 4],
 9=>[7, 3],
 17=>[8, 2],
 18=>[9, 1],
 13=>[3, 7],
 12=>[4, 6],
 15=>[6, 4],
 16=>[7, 3]}
```

and you said:

> problem is it returns a hash with the leftmost index as key and the
>   pair as value. I'm trying to call this recursive function from another
>   function (#sum_pairs) so that I can then format the output I need

Please tell me exactly what you mean by `so that I can then format the output I need`
How would you like the final result to be like?

EDIT#1

For debugging purposes, I put all the results in an array instead and the result looks like this

```
integers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,3,4,5,6,7,8,4,3,2,1]
target_number = 10

=> [{:left_index=>0, :right_index=>8, :values=>[1, 9]},
 {:left_index=>1, :right_index=>7, :values=>[2, 8]},
 {:left_index=>2, :right_index=>6, :values=>[3, 7]},
 {:left_index=>3, :right_index=>5, :values=>[4, 6]},
 {:left_index=>4, :right_index=>11, :values=>[5, 5]},
 {:left_index=>5, :right_index=>10, :values=>[6, 4]},
 {:left_index=>6, :right_index=>9, :values=>[7, 3]},
 {:left_index=>7, :right_index=>17, :values=>[8, 2]},
 {:left_index=>8, :right_index=>18, :values=>[9, 1]},
 {:left_index=>9, :right_index=>13, :values=>[3, 7]},
 {:left_index=>10, :right_index=>12, :values=>[4, 6]},
 {:left_index=>12, :right_index=>15, :values=>[6, 4]},
 {:left_index=>13, :right_index=>16, :values=>[7, 3]},
 {:left_index=>14, :right_index=>17, :values=>[8, 2]}]
```

Please let me know how you want the end result to be like so I can give it a try.

Comment: Sorry about the lazy naming, it was written like that in codewars and I didn't take the time to name them properly. The final output needs to be the hash element with the lowest key value. What I'm most interested in is how to solve this using recursion. I wasn't getting a stack overflow error when calling sums.merge!(#sum_pairs). It returned the correct value

Comment: which would be the lowest value in the array of hashes in Edit#1 ?
right_index=>5 ?